# Display array as table

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to make a c++ code. But it is not working. It should display a 2D array into a table of 9 rows and 8 columns. Can I get some help please?

```
int main() 
{
    int ray[10][10], r, c, n=2;

    for(r=0; r<=10; r++) {
        for(c=0; c<=10; c++) {
            ray[r][c]=n; n=n+2;
        }
    } 
    for(r=0; r<10; r++) {
        for(c=0; c<10; c++) {
            cout << ray[r][c] << " ";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you wrote and what isn't working, otherwise we're doing your work for you.

Comment: I wrote a code and it is working as well but the thing is i want such an output and i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: int main()
{
int ray[10][10], r, c, n=2;
  for(r=0; r<=10; r++)
  {
    for(c=0; c<=10; c++)
    {
    ray[r][c]=n;
    n=n+2;
    }
  }
  for(r=0; r<10; r++)
  {
    for(c=0; c<10; c++)
    {
    cout << ray[r][c] << "  ";
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

Comment: I thought you wanted to display a 9*8 table, but why is it `ray[10][10]`? For the first part, when you assign the value, the loop is incorrect. `ray[10][10]` is a 2D array from `ray[0][0]` to `ray[9][9]`, hence you can't use `r<=10` as it is out of bounds when `r=10`. Also you may want to print a new line, `cout << endl;` after column looping, so that the subsequent row will be displayed on a new line. Else it will be appended to the right.

Comment: Well there are no styling patterns in a `c++` code :/ so you will need to create two arrays yourself. :)

Answer (score 2):

Some pseudocode to help you

```
Create a 2D array
Input the data
Loop from i = 1 to 9
    Loop from j = 1 to 8
        Print array[i][j] + " "
    Print a new line
```

Don't forget to use the correct format identifier if you use `printf`, else use `cout`.
Good luck.

Comment: P.S. what shall I do if I have to display some keywords used in the code in the output?

Comment: What keyword do you mean?